# Programmatically click on a button inside one of the cells in ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How can I simulate a click on a button rendered on the last column of the first row in Ag-Grid? I am able to get the first row using `getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0)`. But have no clue how to proceed further

Any pointers?

** Trying to simulate a click using enzyme wrapper for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I just add a unique id to my button then find it and simulate a click.

```
const component = mount(<bla..>);
component.find('button#id').simulate('click', {});
```